# Не двигается окно без рамки, PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer, framelesswindowhint

Есть код, сгенерированный с помощью *Qt Designer*:

Я отключил рамку:

```
self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
```

но теперь окно не двигается мышкой, куда бы я не тыкал. 
Как исправить?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(259, 301)
        Form.setStyleSheet("QWidget {\n"
"    background-color: gray;\n"
"}")
        Form.setLocale(QtCore.QLocale(QtCore.QLocale.English, QtCore.QLocale.UnitedStates))
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 31, 21))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: orange;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"font-weight: bold;")
        self.pushButton.setLocale(QtCore.QLocale(QtCore.QLocale.English, QtCore.QLocale.UnitedStates))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 0, 31, 21))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: orange;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"font-weight: bold;")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 221, 41))
        self.lineEdit.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.lineEdit.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid orange;\n"
"background-color: white;\n"
"color: black;\n"
"font-size: 15px;\n"
"text-align: center;")
        self.lineEdit.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 120, 221, 172))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.pushButton_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_9.setStyleSheet("background-color: orange;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"font-weight: bold;\n"
"weight: 50px;\n"
"height: 30px;")
        self.pushButton_9.setObjectName("pushButton_9")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_9, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_10 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_10.setStyleSheet("background-color: orange;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"font-weight: bold;\n"
"weight: 50px;\n"
"height: 30px;")
        self.pushButton_10.setObjectName("pushButton_10")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_10, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_11 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_11.setStyleSheet("background-color: orange;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"font-weight: bold;\n"
"weight: 50px;\n"
"height: 30px;")
        self.pushButton_11.setObjectName("pushButton_11")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_11, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: orange;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"font-weight: bold;\n"
"weight: 50px;\n"
"height: 30px;")
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_6, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: orange;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"font-weight: bold;\n"
"weight: 50px;\n"
"height: 30px;")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_5, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: orange;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"font-weight: bold;\n"
"weight: 50px;\n"
"height: 30px;")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_8.setStyleSheet("background-color: orange;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"font-weight: bold;\n"
"weight: 50px;\n"
"height: 30px;")
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_8, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: orange;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"font-weight: bold;\n"
"weight: 50px;\n"
"height: 30px;")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: orange;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"font-weight: bold;\n"
"weight: 50px;\n"
"height: 30px;")
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_7, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_12 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_12.setStyleSheet("background-color: orange;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"font-weight: bold;\n"
"weight: 50px;\n"
"height: 30px;")
        self.pushButton_12.setObjectName("pushButton_12")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_12, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_20 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_20.setStyleSheet("background-color: silver;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"font-weight: bold;\n"
"weight: 50px;\n"
"height: 30px;")
        self.pushButton_20.setObjectName("pushButton_20")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_20, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_19 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_19.setStyleSheet("background-color: silver;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"font-weight: bold;\n"
"weight: 50px;\n"
"height: 30px;")
        self.pushButton_19.setObjectName("pushButton_19")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_19, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayoutWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.gridLayoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 70, 221, 40))
        self.gridLayoutWidget_2.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget_2")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
        self.gridLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.pushButton_15 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
        self.pushButton_15.setStyleSheet("background-color: orange;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"font-weight: bold;\n"
"weight: 30px;\n"
"height: 10px;")
        self.pushButton_15.setObjectName("pushButton_15")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_15, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_14 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
        self.pushButton_14.setStyleSheet("background-color: orange;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"font-weight: bold;\n"
"weight: 30px;\n"
"height: 10px;")
        self.pushButton_14.setObjectName("pushButton_14")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_14, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_17 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
        self.pushButton_17.setStyleSheet("background-color: orange;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"font-weight: bold;\n"
"weight: 30px;\n"
"height: 10px;")
        self.pushButton_17.setObjectName("pushButton_17")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_17, 0, 3, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_16 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget_2)
        self.pushButton_16.setStyleSheet("background-color: orange;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"font-weight: bold;\n"
"weight: 30px;\n"
"height: 10px;")
        self.pushButton_16.setObjectName("pushButton_16")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_16, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_13 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_13.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 0, 31, 21))
        self.pushButton_13.setStyleSheet("background-color: orange;\n"
"color: white;\n"
"font-weight: bold;")
        self.pushButton_13.setObjectName("pushButton_13")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "X"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "-"))
        self.pushButton_9.setText(_translate("Form", "7"))
        self.pushButton_10.setText(_translate("Form", "8"))
        self.pushButton_11.setText(_translate("Form", "9"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("Form", "4"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("Form", "3"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("Form", "2"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("Form", "6"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("Form", "5"))
        self.pushButton_12.setText(_translate("Form", "0"))
        self.pushButton_20.setText(_translate("Form", "."))
        self.pushButton_19.setText(_translate("Form", "="))
        self.pushButton_15.setText(_translate("Form", "-"))
        self.pushButton_14.setText(_translate("Form", "+"))
        self.pushButton_17.setText(_translate("Form", "/"))
        self.pushButton_16.setText(_translate("Form", "*"))
        self.pushButton_13.setText(_translate("Form", "?"))


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint) # !!!!!


if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   w = Widget()
   w.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
...

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint) # !!!!!
        self.old_pos = None

    # вызывается при нажатии кнопки мыши
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):         
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.old_pos = event.pos()

    # вызывается при отпускании кнопки мыши
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.old_pos = None

    # вызывается всякий раз, когда мышь перемещается
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not self.old_pos:
            return
        delta = event.pos() - self.old_pos
        self.move(self.pos() + delta)
...
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]